# Creating Large Objects in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

SQL standard provides large object data types for character data (**clob**) and binary data(**blob**), and in an example, I found them being declared as:

```
attribute_name clob(20KB)
attribute_name blob(10GB)
```

so, I tried the following:

```
create table mydata(
my_movie blob(2GB)
);
```

but, it gave me an error. How is this *large object* created?

Comment: Use `text` instead of `clob`. `bytea` (the natural choice for "blobs") is limited to 1GB but "large objects"  are very complicated to handle. For a complete movie with 10GB I would recommend to store them in the filesystem, not in the database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, isn't there something larger than bytea?

Comment: Not something that's as easy to handle as `bytea`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, still doesn't work: https://pasteboard.co/HECimJ5.png

Comment: Please see [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html) for the correct syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL supports [large objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/largeobjects.html) as related chunks in a `pg_largeobject` table.  You create a large object (separately) then insert a reference to it into your table.  Large objects are more difficult to deal with than `bytea` and require an API beyond pure SQL.

The SQL syntax for creating a table is simple.  Assuming you want a primary key named "id", you can create one like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mydata (id INTEGER, my_movie OID);
```

The `OID` is a reference to a large object.

Because a large object is potentially too large to hold in memory, you'll probably want to read and write them using a streaming interface.  Below is an untested example that uses Java's JDBC interface to create a large object and associate it with an existing record in `mydata`.  Be aware that deleting the record in `mydata` won't delete the large object.

```java
Path moviePath  = ...
int  primaryKey = ...

connection.setAutoCommit(false); // start a transaction (required for large objects)

try (var inputStream = Files.newInputStream(moviePath)) { // Open the file for reading
    // Insert the movie into a mydata record as a Blob
    try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
            "UPDATE mydata SET my_movie = ? WHERE id = ?")) {
        ps.setBlob(1, inputStream);
        ps.setInt(2, primaryKey);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
}

connection.commit();
```

Note that `TEXT` is not appropriate for movie clips, since PostgreSQL disallows the use of codepoint=0 in TEXT and there may be null bytes in binary data.